# Why cpu_count returns 1 on ``virtualbox`` VM hosted on multicore machine

Tags: python, virtual-machine

My computer has `2` cores and `4` logical processors (Linux is run on a `virtualbox`), but in a python notebook, when I run `print cpu_count()`, it returns me `1`. Why is that?

Complete code look like this:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
print cpu_count()
```

Comment: What's your platform?

Comment: I have a virtualbox with Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: On Linux that number is returned by running `os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN')`. If that's returning `1`, it's probably because your VM is only configured with one processor. It doesn't matter how many your host OS has.

Comment: @Jacobian - have you assigned the VM to have more than one processor? VirtualBox defaults to only providing one CPU.

Comment: @slugonamission No, I have not done that. Can you, please, advise me, how to do that?

Comment: `os.sysconf('SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN')` returns me `unexpected token...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused when your `virtualbox` is configured with only one processor. To increase number of processors:

1)  Launch virtualbox
2) Machine->Settings
3) Click on `System` Menu Point
4) Click on `Processor` Tab
5) Select number of processors

Tested on `virtualbox` together with `Linux Mint 17` on `Windows 8` host system.